# How to add new custom sub menu in Sales Admin Menu?

Tags: magento2, menu

[image: Mangento Sales Menubar]

I'd like to add a new submenu called as Deliveries below Transactions submenus. In what kind of way I can achieve this ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

**Add menu.xml inside Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Invigorate_SalesMenu::deliveriesmenu"
             title="Deliveries"
             module="Invigorate_SalesMenu"
             sortOrder="100"
             parent="Magento_Sales::sales_operation"
             action="deliveriesmenu/index/index"
             resource="Invigorate_SalesMenu::deliveries"
        />
    </menu>
</config>
```

**Add acl.xml inside Vendor/Module/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Sales::sales">
                    <resource id="Magento_Sales::sales_operation">
                        <resource id="Invigorate_SalesMenu::deliveries" title="Deliveries" sortOrder="10"/>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Comment: You're welcome. Do upvote and accept if it helped you. thanks :)